# Python 3 class decorator which get applied to the methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, python-decorators

As the title states I am looking for a way to decorate a class, such that when I make a call to the methods the decorator is applied to that call. The main reason behind this would allow me to trap the function calls and their arguments passed. The reason I am not going down the traditional path of decorating the individual methods is do to the fact that the methods may not be known ahead of time as these classes will be extended via a plugin.I am also open to other implementation that people may have to this problem.

```
from functools import wraps


def echo(fh):
    def func_wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if ret is None:
                ret = "empty"
            fn_calls = []
            if args:
                fn_calls.append([func.__name__, args, ret])
            elif kwargs:
                fn_calls.append([func.__name__, kwargs, ret])
            else:
                raise ArgumentError
            collector(fh, fn_calls)
        return wrapper
    return func_wrapper
```

So taking the above decorator and applying it to a class instead of a method.

pseudo code example:

```
@echo(file_)
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self, name):
        print("this is %s" % name)
-----
foo = Foo()
foo.bar("baz")
```

Which would return something like: ['foo.bar', 'baz', 'None']

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why decorator? Why can't you use a metaclass?

Comment: I was think about that also, I just figured that a decorator would provide a cleaner look.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like metaclasses, you could instead use a class decorator:

```
import functools

def _echoit(file, func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        file.write('Echoing func %s\n' % func.__name__)
        file.write('Echoing args %\n' % args)
        file.write('Echoing kwargs %s\n' % kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def echo(file):
    def decorator(cls):
        attrs = vars(cls)
        for k in list(attrs.keys()):
             if callable(attrs[k]):
                 attrs[k] = _echoit(attrs[k], file)
        return cls
    return decorator

@echo(file_)
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self, name):
        print("this is %s" % name)

foo = Foo()
foo.bar("baz")
```

If this is meant for a plugin system, a base class with a custom metaclass would probably be more extensible into the future and would allow you to have custom abstract methods that need to be overridden, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at going down the metaclass route for the reasons you mentioned.